# Keep current tab open (with lightbox open) and open a 2nd tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on setting up a coupon code page and I need the following to happen:

1) My visitor clicks a coupon code reveal button

2) A lightbox appears on the page

3) Simultaneously a new tab is open with the company's website

Right now I have the following

```
/* * * JS for lightbox * * */
  <script src="//static.leadpages.net/leadboxes/current/embed.js" async defer></script>

/* * * Link I want audience to click * * */
  <a href="" data-leadbox-popup="14029df53f72a2:12f5b8283b46dc"

/* * * Opens the new tab to the company website * * */  
  onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com');">click me</a>
```

The problem is that it automatically takes the viewer to the company website instead of staying on the current page so they can see the coupon code light box first so they can copy the coupon code and THEN go to the company website.

I have tried various other ways to get this to work such as:

```
onclick="window.open('#','_blank');window.open(this.href,'_self');">
```

But when I do this the lightbox doesn't get triggered and the viewer can't see the coupon code.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried something like this: <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" data-leadbox-popup="14029df53f72a2:12f5b8283b46dc">click me</a>

Comment: Just tried and it opens the light box just fine, but doesn't open google in a new tab. <a href="http://www.google.com"; target="new"; data-leadbox-popup="14029df53f72a2:12f5b8283b46dc">click me</a>